# How to use Ionic proxy in conjunction with AWS SDK

Tags: ionic-framework, aws-sdk

Using Ionic 4.4.0 and aws-sdk 2.157.0.  I'm trying to create an S3 bucket from my local web browser, but am running into CORS problems when attempting to run the following code, method createBucketByCompanyKey():

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

@Injectable()
export class AwsProvider {

  private accessKeyId:string = 'myAccessKey';
  private secretAccessKey:string = 'mySuperSecret';
  private region:string = 'us-east-1';

  constructor() {
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: this.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: this.secretAccessKey, region: this.region});
  }

  createBucketByCompanyKey(companyKey){

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    let params = {
      Bucket: companyKey,
      CreateBucketConfiguration: {
        LocationConstraint: this.region
      }
    };
    s3.createBucket(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
  }
}
```

This gives me the error

> Failed to load https://s3.amazonaws.com/-KwzdjmyrHiMBCqHH1ZC: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Which led me to [this post here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/proxy-problems-with-ionic/43354) after several hours of googling.  It appears I need to run ionic through a proxy.  I've also tried changing my "path" to http://localhost:8100, but stuck I remain.

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {},
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "proxyUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also come across posts telling my to [download a Chrome extension](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjO96PnwuDXAhUBhyYKHXkGDisQFgg3MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fallow-control-allow-origi%2Fnlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AOvVaw2GlWNT_ZHGklgR26Qux_k-) that disables CORS, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas on how to setup this proxy to work with AWS' SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the proxies.  For Mac, enter in the following in the terminal to open a Google Chrome browser with CORS disabled.

> open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

Compliments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome).